# To set a minimum/default value for the memory of a firebase extension function

Tags: firebase-extensions

I'm trying to set a default/minimum value for a function resource in my Firebase extension, I do it like [this](https://github.com/pdfplum/pdfplum/blob/main/http-pdf-generator/extension.yaml#L60) as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/publishers/parameters#system_parameters) by setting the `memory` property of the function resources, but when I try to install it, the value of this property is completely ignored:
[image]
And even though I provided 1024 for its value, its default value is 256MB and the minimum value is 128MB (my provided property is not respected neither as default nor minimum memory)

It is causing confusion for users as reported in these issues:
https://github.com/pdfplum/pdfplum/issues/14
https://github.com/pdfplum/pdfplum/issues/11

Is there anyway to set the minimum required memory for a function resource of an extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you override memory of a resource the advanced parameters have no effect on that resource. This applies to both hardcoded values (as in your example) or custom parameters: https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/c6945fef573c0cb87dbaf64ba2066737cd7c3a1e/storage-resize-images/extension.yaml#L60

If you want advanced settings to control memory configuration of your functions, then you should remove memory setting completely. Ex: https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/c6945fef573c0cb87dbaf64ba2066737cd7c3a1e/firestore-send-email/extension.yaml#L51

There's currently no way to control the default/minimum value in the options of the advanced params. You either provide your own memory options (see storage-resize-images example linked above) or you use default options of the advanced params.

There appears to be a little bug though -- when all resources of an extension have their memory manually set, the memory option in advanced settings should not be showing (I'll file a bug for that).

Comment: Thanks! I think other than the bug you mentioned, the documents are not aligned with what you stated here. In this document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/publishers/parameters#system_parameters it is talking about a "memory" property in "Corresponding field in properties" column, it is not named "availableMemoryMb" as provided in storage-resize-images example.

Comment: Also while investigating the cause of this issue https://github.com/pdfplum/pdfplum/issues/11 I noticed availableMemoryMB is ignored and the memory provided in advanced settings is respected for the function resource, so even though the memory was set to 1GB in the custom parameter, the function ran out of memory in runtime and setting the memory value in the advanced parameters to 1GB fixed the issue. It made things very confusing for the users. Because suddenly new deployments (affected by this bug) were not working because of low memory deployments of the function.

Comment: You're right, I missed that there's a typo in the docs. It should be `availableMemoryMb` not `memory`. Fixing that as well. Thanks!

Comment: `availableMemoryMB` is also incorrect (will be ignored), it must be `availableMemoryMb`.